# Vertical align text in div according the height of a floating image

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, vertical-alignment

I want to build an html page that shows image with description, the description and the image are dinamically generated, and is possible to find this two common situation:

[image: unwrapped image]

```
<div style="width:500px; padding:10px; border:solid 1px;">
  <div style="width:100%; overflow: auto; border:solid 1px;">
    <img style="float:right; width:40%" src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempus justo pharetra, tincidunt erat nec, euismod quam. Fusce vel purus aliquet, posuere nulla ac, porta urna. Aliquam feugiat ligula vitae maximus tincidunt.
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: wrapped image]

```
<div style="width:500px; padding:10px; border:solid 1px;">
  <div style="width:100%; overflow: auto; border:solid 1px;">
    <img style="float:right; width:40%" src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempus justo pharetra, tincidunt erat nec, euismod quam. Fusce vel purus aliquet, posuere nulla ac, porta urna. Aliquam feugiat ligula vitae maximus tincidunt. Suspendisse vel tristique massa. Ut lobortis sapien nec libero varius, vitae ullamcorper risus pretium. Nunc vulputate posuere auctor. Phasellus pulvinar nibh a risus semper, a lobortis justo ultricies. Etiam at pretium ligula. Nullam lobortis, nisl nec sollicitudin vestibulum, turpis neque porta neque, pellentesque egestas ipsum nunc id nisl. Morbi quis lacus quam. Pellentesque eget congue neque. Vestibulum elementum arcu nec condimentum posuere. Donec risus lorem, ornare pharetra ex a, lobortis molestie nunc. Suspendisse iaculis est eros, eu vestibulum nisi accumsan eget. Proin eget eleifend eros. 
  </div>
</div>
```

While the first text is too short to wrap the image, the second is enough long to wrap it.

I like this effect but i want a little change in the first case, so here is my question:

Is possible to vertical align the text such that is vertical centered according to the image height? (of course i want to preserve the wrap effect with longer text)

Graphically:

i want this:

[image: actual result]

to become this:

[image: wished result]

Comment: Considering two cases, I don't think so. You probably need to use JavaScript to achieve the effect.

Comment: good answer but i'm here to know if is possible to achieve this result using only css

Comment: I would also say no as you would need to know if the text was wrapping before you applied the styles in order to center it - ie you would need to calculate the height of the container, compare that to the height of the image and then apply the centering styles if the image was the same size

Comment: I also, would recommend some Javascript..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/u032xpLr/) is how you would do it

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="something">
        <img src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg" />
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempus justo pharetra, tincidunt erat nec, euismod quam. Fusce vel purus aliquet, posuere nulla ac, porta urna. Aliquam feugiat ligula vitae maximus tincidunt.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="something">
        <img src="http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg" />
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam tempus justo pharetra, tincidunt erat nec, euismod quam. Fusce vel purus aliquet, posuere nulla ac, porta urna. Aliquam feugiat ligula vitae maximus tincidunt. Suspendisse vel tristique massa. Ut lobortis sapien nec libero varius, vitae ullamcorper risus pretium. Nunc vulputate posuere auctor. Phasellus pulvinar nibh a risus semper, a lobortis justo ultricies. Etiam at pretium ligula. Nullam lobortis, nisl nec sollicitudin vestibulum, turpis neque porta neque, pellentesque egestas ipsum nunc id nisl. Morbi quis lacus quam. Pellentesque eget congue neque. Vestibulum elementum arcu nec condimentum posuere. Donec risus lorem, ornare pharetra ex a, lobortis molestie nunc. Suspendisse iaculis est eros, eu vestibulum nisi accumsan eget. Proin eget eleifend eros.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:500px;
    padding:10px;
    border:solid 1px;
}
.something {
    width:100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border:solid 1px;
}
.something>img {
    float:right;
    width:40%
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numberOfItems = $(".container").length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
        var imageHeight = $(".container:eq(" + i + ")").children(".something").children("img").height();
        var divHeight = $(".container:eq(" + i + ")").children(".something").children("div").height();
        if (divHeight < imageHeight) {
            $(".container:eq("+i+")").children(".something").children("div").css({
                "margin-top": (imageHeight - divHeight) / 2 + "px"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT**

For the jQuery above to work, include the snippet below in your `<header>` tag (before the calls to all your jQuery documents)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) website for more information on this

Comment: That's JS **+ jQuery**.

Comment: @DJDavid98 Yes it is, is that an issue?

Comment: You might want to make it clear so that the OP knows you're also using an external library, considering no [tag:javascript] nor [tag:jquery] tag is present on the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make wrapper div display:table and text div display:table-cell; verticle-align:middle;

If it dont work then also apply overflow:hidden on the text div